# openssh-server doesn't start in Docker container

Tags: ssh, openssh, docker, container

I am having a weird problem.

I am not able to ssh to docker container having ip address `172.17.0.61`.

I am getting following error:

```
$ ssh 172.17.0.61
ssh: connect to host 172.17.0.61 port 22: Connection refused
```

My `Dockerfile` does contain `openssh-server` installation step:

```
RUN apt-get -y install curl runit openssh-server
```

And also step to start ssh:

```
RUN service ssh start
```

What could be the issue?

When I enter into container using [`nsenter`](https://github.com/jpetazzo/nsenter) and start `ssh` service then I am able to ssh. But while creating container `ssh-server` doesn't seems to start.

What should I do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Container vs. Image**

The `RUN` statement is used to run commands when building the docker image. 
With `ENTRYPOINT` and `CMD` you can define what to run when you start a container using that image. 
See [Dockerfile Reference](https://docs.docker.com/reference/builder/) for explanations how to use them.

**Services**

There is not preinstalled init-system in the containers, so you cannot use `service ... start` in a container. 
Consider starting the process in the `CMD` statement as foreground process or use an init-system like Phusion or Supervisord.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion there is a better approach:

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04.1
EXPOSE 22
COPY docker-entrypoint.sh /docker-entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x /docker-entrypoint.sh
RUN apt-get install -y openssh-server

ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "/docker-entrypoint.sh"]

# THIS PART WILL BE REPLACED IF YOU PASS SOME OTHER COMMAND TO docker RUN
CMD while true; do echo "default arg" && sleep 1; done
```

**docker-entrypoint.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
service ssh restart
exec "$@"
```

Build command
`docker build -t sshtest .`

The benefit of this approach is that your ssh daemon will always start when you use `docker run`, but you can also specify optional arguments e.g.:

`docker run sshtest` will print `default arg` every 1 second
whether `docker run sshtest sh -c 'while true; do echo "passed arg" && sleep 3; done'` will print `passed arg` every 3 seconds